# Counting a list of words in multiple textfiles in a directory Python

Tags: python

I would like to first

1. count if the word in a list of words appear in multiple textfiles in a directory
2. count how many times the word in a list of words appear in multiple textiles in a directory

I have already a "list_words" that is a string list of words that i am interested in.
then, I call each file using a loop,

```
for i in range(1,10):

filename=open(directory+'text'+str(i),'r')
textfile=filename.read()
words_in_textfile=re.split('\W{1,}',textfile)
```

and i am stuck how to go about this, i would really appreciate help!!

Comment: Logic is wrong to iterate over the multiple textfiles inside a directory you should use `glob` module and loop over the files then read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the re module, the Counter object from the collections module, and the Path object from the pathlib module.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

counter = Counter()   #Create a counter object for keeping track of wordcounts.
for word in your_list_of_words:    #iterate through your list of words and for each word...
    for file in Path("your_directory").glob("*.txt"):   #Iterate through all .txt files in "your_directory"
        with open(file, 'r') as stream:    #open the file
            counter.update(re.findall(word, stream.read()))    #Update your counter object with the count of all the instances of 'word' found in 'file'.
```

This will give you a total count of each word across all files. If you want a count of each word for each file you may want to use a dictionary and update it each time. e.g.

```
counter = {}
for word in your_list_of_words:
    counter[word] = {}
    for file in Path("your_directory").glob("*.txt"):
        with open(file, 'r') as stream:
            counter[word][file] = len(re.findall(word, stream.read()))
```

Worth noting this will find all instances of that word, even if it's in the middle of another word e.g.

```
re.findall('cat', "catastrophic catcalling cattery cats")
returns
['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat']
```

so you may want to play with the regex, e.g.

```
word = 'cat'
re.findall(fr"\b{word}\b", "catastrophic catcalling cattery cats"))
returns []
```

which may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: This was working well but at the end i get "error: missing ), unterminated subpattern" do you know why?

Comment: It probably means somewhere in your regex you have opened a bracket and not closed it.