# Adding occurrences of words in a directory

Tags: python

I have some some code that works for telling me how many times a word appears in each file in a directory, but I can't figure out the best way to either a) add these occurrences together to get a total, or b) just count the number of times the word appears in the whole directory.

Here is the code that works for looking at how many times the word appears in each file in a directory:

```
keywords = ['river']

for doc in docs:
    with open(doc, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        keywords_found = {}
        for key in keywords: 
            found = re.findall(key, data, re.I)
            if found:
                keywords_found[key] = len(found)
        print(doc, keywords_found)
```

Ideally I would like to edit that above code to have it produce a final count for each keyword at the end.

However, I'm willing to do this in a different block of code entirely.

I have tried all the solutions from this page [Counting a list of words in multiple textfiles in a directory Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67721342/counting-a-list-of-words-in-multiple-textfiles-in-a-directory-python)

This is the first solution I tried:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

counter = Counter()   #Create a counter object for keeping track of wordcounts.
for word in your_list_of_words:    #iterate through your list of words and for each word...
    for file in Path("your_directory").glob("*.txt"):   #Iterate through all .txt files in "your_directory"
        with open(file, 'r') as stream:    #open the file
            counter.update(re.findall(word, stream.read()))    #Update your counter object with the count of all the instances of 'word' found in 'file'.
```

And I got a multiple repeat error at line counter.update(re.findall(word, stream.read()))

Then I tried this solution:

```
word - 'river'

re.findall(fr"\b{word}\b", all_docs)
returns []
```

I got a Syntax error at the returns [] line

Comment: You're trying to subtract not assign and (as I'd guess the error tells you) aren't in a function when you're trying to return...

Comment: You're talking about the last bock of code?

Comment: The last block, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided a sample of raw files to test the code. But anyways, if you want to count the final count for a list of words in all documents, you can probably modify your code as follows:

```
keywords = ['river', 'tree', ...]
keywords_found = {word:[] for word in keywords}

for doc in docs:
    with open(doc, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        for key in keywords: 
            found = re.findall(key, data, re.I)
            if found:
                keywords_found[key].append(len(found)) 
            else:         
                keywords_found[key].append(0)
```

Then at the end, you can count the total number of count for each keyword:

```
final_count = {k:sum(v) for k, v in keywords_found.items()}
```

And if you wish, you can print with custom text:

```
print("The total counts of keywords are:")
for key, count in final_count.items():
    print(f"{key} = {count} times")
```

Comment: Why collect in lists and sum at the end instead of simply adding?

Comment: Because there are several _docs_ that we want to search the keywords in (based on the for loop). Therefore, we need to save the count of keywords obtained from each document in a list to be able to calculate the final count at the end. @KellyBundy

Comment: That reasoning makes no sense. You absolutely don't need lists for that.

Comment: Would you post your suggestion as an answer, please? That helps to clarify your strategy. @KellyBundy

Comment: Starting with `keywords_found = {word:0 for word in keywords}` and then `keywords_found[key] += len(found)`.

Comment: I see your point and I agree that we can directly increment the values of the dictionary. Nevertheless, what I understood from the question is that the user may want to know the values added from each document and later, in a separate block of code, calculate the sum. If that is not the case, I agree that the code can be modified based on your kind suggestion. @KellyBundy

Comment: How do you use your lists for that, though? Let's say you have three docs and the list for some word is `[16, 9]`. How do you know which two of the three files contributed those two numbers?

Comment: With this solution @Ardalan1 I get a Type error: 'int' object is not iterable on line where final_count is defined.

Comment: @KellyBundy You are absolutely right. I added a line for adding zero if no item is found.

Comment: What do you think `re.findall` returns when it doesn't find any matches?

Comment: @DezMiller Is any of the values of the dictionary _keywords_found_ outside of a list? Please paste the outcome of the keywords_found to double-check.

Comment: @KellyBundy can you explain how your suggestion works a little more?  Your solution doesn't seem to be an improvement on my existing code. The only difference is when a keyword does not appear it lists keyword: 0, whereas my code just leaves it out. I am still trying to figure out a way to add the occurrences together.

Comment: @DezMiller Same as this answer, except for the two modifications I mentioned.

Comment: @DezMiller Judging by your comments, I guess you didn't copy&paste this solution as a whole but tried to incorporate bits of it into your code?

Comment: @Ardalan1 The revised code works! Thanks so much. I don't have enough reputation to upvote unfortunately.